# how load google chart with ajax call?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-visualization

i wrote google donut chart with ajax loading but i am not able to get the output please help me...
my script code is like this

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
$.ajax({
    url: "ProjectCategoryChart",
    dataType:'JSON',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
         alert("a"+  data.aCount );
         $("#acount").val(data.aCount);
         $("#bcount").val(data.bCount);
         $("#ccount").val(data.cCount);
         $("#dcount").val(data.dCount);
         $("#nocount").val(data.noCount);
         google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
     }
    });


  function drawChart() {
      alert("a value"+ parseInt($("#acount").val()));
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Categorized', 'No.of Projects'],
      ['A',     parseInt($("#acount").val())],
      ['B',     parseInt($("#bcount").val())],
      ['C',  parseInt($("#ccount").val())],
      ['D', parseInt($("#dcount").val())],
      ['Not Categorized',    parseInt($("#nocount").val())]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Project Categorization',
      pieHole: 0.4,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

and my html code is

```
<div id="donutchart" style="width: 600px; height: 350px;"></div>
         <input type="hidden" id="acount" value=""/>
         <input type="hidden" id="bcount" value=""/>
         <input type="hidden" id="ccount" value=""/>
         <input type="hidden" id="dcount" value=""/>
         <input type="hidden" id="nocount" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the Visualization API is loaded when you call any of the API components, which requires waiting on a callback from the loader.  The easy way to do this is to start your AJAX call after the API is loaded:

```
function drawChart () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ProjectCategoryChart',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            // you can remove these if you don't need them for something else
            alert('a'+ data.aCount);
            $('#acount').val(data.aCount);
            $('#bcount').val(data.bCount);
            $('#ccount').val(data.cCount);
            $('#dcount').val(data.dCount);
            $('#nocount').val(data.noCount);

            var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Categorized', 'No.of Projects'],
                ['A', data.aCount],
                ['B', data.bCount],
                ['C', data.cCount],
                ['D', data.dCount],
                ['Not Categorized', data.noCount]
            ]);

            var options = {
                title: 'Project Categorization',
                pieHole: 0.4,
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
            chart.draw(dataTable, options);
        }
    });
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```

Comment: Thank you,it solved my problem.but still i am facing problem while loading charts.my requirement is like this i have a menu bar with 4 links(list items)when i click on link it should open page(this page contains graph).while moving from one page to other it is still taking so much time some times its not displaying.after reloading the page it is displaying graph

Comment: It sounds like you have performance issues with your data source; once the data is received by the browser, the time to render the chart is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
$.ajax({
    url: "ProjectCategoryChart",
    dataType:'JSON',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
          alert("a"+  data.aCount );
          var dataValues = {
              aCount : data.aCount,
              bCount : data.bCount,
              cCount : data.cCount,
              dCount : data.dCount,
              nCount : data.nCount
          };
          drawChart(dataValues);
     }
});

function drawChart(data) {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Categorized', 'No.of Projects'],
        ['A', data.aCount],
        ['B', data.bCount],
        ['C', data.cCount],
        ['D', data.dCount],
        ['Not Categorized', data.nCount]
    ]);
    var options = {
      title: 'Project Categorization',
      pieHole: 0.4,
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: i have changed google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart); to drawchart() but i am nit getting any thing my  alert("a value"+ parseInt($("#acount").val())); value is NAN.and i am geeting error in console like    Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'arrayToDataTable'